# After running this code it spits out the same value for both dice, how can I fix the random value to be different each time?

Tags: python

```
 class Die:
    def __init__ (self, face, face_value):
        self.face = face
        self.face_value = face_value
    def roll(self):
        return print(self.face)
```

**I later import this class because I have them in two different files.**

```
import random
from DieClass import Die
num = random.randint(1,6)


    if num == 1:
        face = ( ' ------\n|       |\n|   o   |\n|       |\n ------')
    elif num == 2:
        face =  (' ------\n|       |\n| o   o |\n|       |\n ------')
    elif num == 3:
        face =  (' ------\n|   o   |\n|   o   |\n|   o   |\n ------')
    elif num == 4:
        face =  (' ------\n| o   o |\n| o   o |\n|       |\n ------')
    elif num == 5:
        face =  (' ------\n| o   o |\n| o   o |\n|   o   |\n ------')
    elif num == 6:
        face = (' ------\n| o   o |\n| o   o |\n| o   o |\n ------' )
```

**Here are my face variables. How do I make them random each time?**

```
    class Dicegame(Die):
        def __init__ (self, name):
            self.name = name

        def play(self):
            Die1 = Die(face, num)
            return Die1.roll()
```

**Here I am calling my class.**

```
    Dice1 = Dicegame('name')
    Dice1.play()
    Dice2 = Dicegame('bob')
    Dice2.play()
```

Comment: try running it in a loop a couple 10's of times, 
you might just be getting lucky

Comment: his die doesn't roll, bro. see above.

Answer (score 0):

You are not rolling the dice. Change your die class like this.

```
class Die:
    def __init__ (self, face, face_value):
        self.face = face
        self.face_value = face_value
    def roll(self):
        self.face = random.randint(1, 6)
        return print(self.face)
```

I also refactored the whole code. It works two times. Change accordingly.

```
import random

class Die:
    def __init__ (self, face_value):
        self.face_value = face_value
    def roll(self):
        self.face_value = random.randint(1, 6)
        return self.face_value

class Dicegame(Die):
    def __init__ (self, name):
        self.name = name

    def play(self, num):
        Die1 = Die(num)
        return Die1.roll()

def print_state(name, num):
    face = ''
    if num == 1:
        face = ( ' ------\n|       |\n|   o   |\n|       |\n ------')
    elif num == 2:
        face =  (' ------\n|       |\n| o   o |\n|       |\n ------')
    elif num == 3:
        face =  (' ------\n|   o   |\n|   o   |\n|   o   |\n ------')
    elif num == 4:
        face =  (' ------\n| o   o |\n| o   o |\n|       |\n ------')
    elif num == 5:
        face =  (' ------\n| o   o |\n| o   o |\n|   o   |\n ------')
    elif num == 6:
        face = (' ------\n| o   o |\n| o   o |\n| o   o |\n ------' )
    else:
        face = ''
    print(name)
    print(face)

num1 = random.randint(1, 6)
num2 = random.randint(1, 6)

Dice1 = Dicegame('name')
print_state('name', num1)
new_state1 = Dice1.play(num1)

Dice2 = Dicegame('bob')
print_state('bob', num2)
new_state2 = Dice2.play(num2)

print_state('name', new_state1)
print_state('bob', new_state2)
```

Comment: Can you show me what code you are using to call that. Above your if loops are shifted by a tab, is there a code above or not.

Comment: For printing you need to get what is the new value and then print again. Shift your printing code into a function.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Um, if I wanted to add up the die numbers, how would I do that?

Comment: store values in the array as they come.